# iPhone App SIze jumps from 12mb to 31mb while processing

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, size

When I submitted my app, it was 12mb but going now through processing it jumped to 31mb. I think this is due to the armv6 and armv7 architectures that weren't added before.

But still, 19mb is outrageous. How can I go under 20mb (the 3g downloadable limit) if the arm architectures are 19mb? And, I don't want to cut one of them off.

Am I doing something wrong? I dont think I uncompressed my textures, because it said I was 12mb before processing.

As of now, I rejected my binary and am trying to figure out a good way to cut app size.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accurately measure the size of binary when it'll be in the app store:

http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/12/21/20mb-limit-finding-the-real-size-of-an-app-binary/

To find out if you have any unused graphics files in your app, use the tool "Slender":

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/slender/id493656257?mt=12

If you have a lot of large PNG image files, you can replace them with JPEG's, as long as they don't use transparency.

Comment: So are the arm architectures really 19mb? Or is something else going on?

Comment: @user1190150, it must be a really large application to reach over 20MB in size. Do you have large database(s) and multimedia files included in it? Otherwise, it's difficult to explain. I've seen apps with 40K lines of code with size ~10 MB.

Comment: I have around 5mb textures, 2mb audio, 4mb dlls, rest are minor. I dont know why after in went into review process it jumped to 31mb!